# select data if exist either on both table or one of the tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Im working on search using php and SQL. What I'm trying to achieve is get the data if it exist in any of the two tables or both.

**This is my sql.**

```
SELECT * FROM history_search 
INNER JOIN history_subs ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword 
WHERE history_search.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%' OR history_subs.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%`'
```

**history_subs**

```
id, keyword, illegal, whitelist (1, Spotify.com, (Artists, api, community, investors, support, labs), open)
```

**history_search**

```
id, keyword, result, blacklist (1, meristone.com, 20, 0), (2, spotify.com, 19, 2),(3, cjrtec.com, 10, 1)
```

My problem is, it wont display data if keyword dont exist on both tables.

Hope you help me.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: sorry Ill add it

Comment: That is what inner join do, you can add or is null.

Comment: Could you add table definitions?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it would be better to use *union*

```
SELECT * FROM history_search 
right JOIN history_subs ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword 
WHERE history_search.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%' OR history_subs.keyword LIKE 
'%$keyword%'
union 
SELECT * FROM history_search 
left JOIN history_subs ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword 
WHERE history_search.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%' OR history_subs.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use full outer join if your criteria is to show result if it exists in any of the tables.

furthermore, If you use where condition on full outer join, your query will be converted to inner join implicitly

so the final query,

EDIT: Apparently Full Outer Join is not supported in MySql. Here is the alternative approach to Full Outer Join

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM history_search 
LEFT JOIN history_subs 
  ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword AND history_search.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%'
UNION
SELECT 
  *
FROM history_subs
LEFT JOIN history_search
  ON history_search.keyword = history_subs.keyword AND history_subs.keyword LIKE '%$keyword%`'
```

Comment: I get this warning sir, `Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object`

Comment: I believe that you are getting this error from php? right?

Comment: yes, `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` this line, I just change the `INNER JOIN` to `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: This won't correctly search for results that are present in `history_subs` but not in `history_search`

Comment: I suggest you to first try this query on sql editor, after that you can port it to your application. I am not php guy so I cannot help you about that

Comment: I made a small change, since the query is full outer join It makes sense to use  keyword  on both sides